# Should (and how can) non-critical logs be sent to /var/log/messages using logger(1)?

Tags: linux, rsyslog, logger

I have a cron script logging msgs via `| logger …`.

1. I am understanding that `/var/log/syslog` is mainly for critical or err msgs and `/var/log/messages` is for informational, non-critical msgs.
2. If the previous is true (I may be mistaken), I’m not sure how to log only unimportant, mundane msgs to JUST `/var/log/messages`? All of the `-p` (priority) parameters I have tried with logger log to both or none. Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: oh! I've found all major Linux distributions I've used have phased out /var/log/messages and syslog in favor of journald/journalct (which can be used as syslog replacement, but can do more). So, the answer to your question might be (I honestly don't know – I'm not familiar with the differences there) pretty dependent on what Linux distro (and version) you're running on. Would you mind filling us in?

Comment: I'm using this on Raspbian but, I thought it was also similar on Ubuntu. I thought using logger with scripts was still pretty standard but, I'm certainly open to learning new solutions. I will look into journal*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you got the idea that `/var/log/syslog` is only for critical/error messages, maybe it's true on some distros but it's not the case for Debian and derivative distributions.   Debian policy has specific guidelines on how the various syslog facilities are to be used (and what kinds of programs should use which facilities), and uses them with more precision and focus than some distros.

Anyway, you need to look at the syslog configuration on the target machine to find out exactly what kinds of log messages are logged to particular files.

e.g. on a standard Debian install, `/etc/rsyslog.conf` has the following for `/var/log/syslog`:

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none      -/var/log/syslog
```

i.e. everything but facilities `auth` and `authpriv`.

and for `/var/log/messages`:

```
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
    auth,authpriv.none;\
    cron,daemon.none;\
    mail.none       -/var/log/messages
```

In short, on Debian and derivatives, /var/log/syslog is a dumping ground for almost everything (except auth-related stuff), and /var/log/messages is for info, notice, and warning messages for everything except auth, cron, daemon, and mail stuff.

Syslog facility `cron`, `daemon` or `user` may be more appropriate for your needs, they are defined with the following rules in Debian:

```
#cron.*             /var/log/cron.log
daemon.*            -/var/log/daemon.log
user.*              -/var/log/user.log
```

(I can't remember if `cron.log` is commented out by default or if I did that myself. I think it's by default, probably because cron.log gets very noisy otherwise)

I haven't used Raspbian much, but I imagine that Raspbian probably has the same or very similar `rsyslog.conf` as Debian.

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer.

Comment: Your quote "/var/log/syslog is a dumping ground for almost everything" is the historical concept I did not understand. My cron script informationals (i.e.: basically just weather data), are currently being logged into all of the log files by default; user, syslog, messages, etc. I just wondered if I should quiet that down, maybe by using a specific -p priority and facility setting. But, I accept that I should just filter events when analyzing whatever log file. I suspect the proper answer is to create and maintain an application-specific log file?

Comment: It's easy enough to use a different syslog facility.  `local0` to `local7` are specifically reserved for local use, but you'd need to configure your syslog daemon (almost certainly rsyslog) to write such messages to specific file(s).    rsyslog also has features for filtering log messages to different files based on regex matches, again that will require configuring rsyslog.    Or just open a file for write inside your application and log directly to it (which will require either pre-creating the file or rwx permissions on the directory containing the file and rx on directories above it).